# Need a recommendation to use a testing platform

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, billing

We are working on billing system (java based module)for that we would like to have a testing framework. That testing framework should be able to adoptable for any type of billing scenarios(eg: utility bill payments, water/electricity/or any other type billing) Normally the billing entity have common attributes like customer name/usage/ etc..I would like to pick a suitable testing platform to test our billing module.

It can be opensource/licensed software.

Can anybody suggest such a framework/engine?

Comment: You'll have to provide a bit more info for this 'billing system' - if you want to get some useful answers. What technologies are used..etc... See [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest following based on your given little description about your need :

1 - For functionality testing and to make all your scenarios automate use [Selenium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/)

2 -Then if you want to priorities your testes , want to run tests through XML , want to run multiple tests then you can use [TestNG Framework](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-introduction/)

Above are totally open source tool and you will get real benefit of those by scripting. They allow you to do scripting using programming languages like Java , Python , ruby and a little more. You will get all details once you visit my given links in above 2 points.

According to your given requirements I think above 2 tools are enough to make everything automate for testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna go for open source tool, then I'd recommend Selenium Webdriver with TestNG Framework. You can get lot of documentation and help on web.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for Cucumber for describing various test scenarios (and their dependencies).
These scenarios will be backed by jUnit for gluing the description to executable code. jUnit will typically be used to write low level tests as well (for use by developers). 
Cucumber has the benefit of giving you reports and can serve well for discussion with users and their representatives.